# Layout not display on frontend Module magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

There is some problem with layout not load with frontend in magento Module.

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Way_SaleWithus>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Way_SaleWithus>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <SaleWithus>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Way_SaleWithus</module>
                    <frontName>SaleWithus</frontName>
                </args>
            </SaleWithus>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <SaleWithus>
                    <file>SaleWithus.xml</file>
                </SaleWithus>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>  
</config>
```

**SaleWithus.xml**
Location :  app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/SaleWithus.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
        <SaleWithus_index_index>
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="core/template" name="SaleWithus" template="SaleWithus/SaleWithus.phtml" />
            </reference>
        </SaleWithus_index_index>
    </layout>
```

**SaleWithus.phtml**
Location app/design/frontend/base/default/template/SaleWithus/SaleWithus.phtml

```
<div>
<h4>Hello World!!</h4>
</div>
```

**IndexController.php**

```
<?php
class Way_SaleWithus_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
//         if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
//            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
//            return;
//        }
//        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Login-Required', 'true');
//        $this->loadLayout();
//        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
//        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
//        $this->renderLayout();
        $this->loadLayout();
            $this->renderLayout();
            echo "subhash";
    }
    protected function _getSession()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    }
}
?>
```

Where am I going wrong with code?

Comment: couple of things that stand out, your layout file is called saleus.xml, but in your config.xml it's listed as sales.xml. Also your config.xml is missing a closing </config> tag, lastly your phtml file is listed being named as saleus.xml, but should have the extension .phtml to match the template definition of your block.

Comment: Please now all code change but get same

Comment: @LazyLion Activate the logs in magento and keep an eye on them. Usually layout errors are thrown there. Also, change 'SaleWithus_index_index' to 'saleWithus_index_index' in layout xml.

Comment: 2014-10-01T08:15:30+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document  in F:\xampp\htdocs\magento\test2\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout\Update.php on line 450
2014-10-01T08:15:30+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():     &lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot;?&gt;  in F:\xampp\htdocs\magento\test2\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout\Update.php on line 450  could you help me with this error

Comment: still now i am cant getting any error or any output

Answer (score 0):

There are some major issues with your xml, it should be as below.

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
      <modules>
        <Way_SaleWithus>
          <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Way_SaleWithus>
      </modules>
      <frontend>
        <routers>
          <salewithus>
            <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                <module>Way_SaleWithus</module>
                <frontName>salewithus</frontName>
              </args>
          </salewithus>
        </routers>
            <layout>
              <updates>
                <salewithus>
                  <file>salewithus.xml</file>
                </salewithus>
              </updates>
            </layout>
      </frontend>>
    </config>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento, Except the class names, it is better to set everything in small letters. The function names too has to be in camelCase letters only.

The above config.xml is messed up with all types of letter cases in English Language. There the problem comes. If eveything is fine, the layout.xml has to be as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
        <salewithus_index_index>
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="core/template" name="salewithus" template="SaleWithus/salesithus.phtml" />
            </reference>
        </salewithus_index_index>
    </layout>
```

Config.xml has to be as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
      <modules>
        <Way_SaleWithus>
          <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Way_SaleWithus>
      </modules>
      <frontend>
        <routers>
          <salewithus>
            <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                <module>Way_SaleWithus</module>
                <frontName>salewithus</frontName>
              </args>
          </salewithus>
        </routers>
            <layout>
              <updates>
                <salewithus>
                  <file>salewithus.xml</file>
                </salewithus>
              </updates>
            </layout>
      </frontend>>
    </config>
```

Change ur template file name as in below path:`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/SaleWithus/salewithus.phtml`

Layout.xml as below path:Location : `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/salewithus.xml`